# How can I make FTP connections secure in WHM?

Tags: security, https, ftp

For security reasons (since FTP transmits passwords and files in plain text), I want to force users of my shared hosting to use FTPS or SFTP instead of regular FTP.

I am using WHM but have limited account (no root access). What options do I have to enforce all FTP connections are secure?

Answer (score 1):

For FTP over TLS (FTPS), from the [cPanel & WHM 11.38 Documentation](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/FtpConfig):

> **To configure your ProFTP server:**
>
> Next to TLS Encryption Support, select whether you wish for TLS encryption for FTP connections to be Optional or Required.
>
> **To configure your Pure-FTP server:**
>
> Next to TLS Encryption Support, select 1 of the following options:
>
> **Disabled** — Disables TLS encryption.  
>   **Optional** — Allows your users to
>   specify whether they wish to use TLS encryption. 
>   **Required (Command)** — Requires TLS encryption on all commands being issued to the FTP
>   server. This will help to protect login and password information.
>   
>  **Required (Command/Data)** — Requires TLS encryption on both commands
>   being issued to the FTP server and data coming to and from the FTP
>   server. This will protect both passwords and files being exchanged
>   between client and server.

Select "Required" for ProFTP, or "Required (Command)" at minimum for Pure-FTP, depending which FTP server you have installed.

This should be located here:

> Home >> Service Configuration >> FTP Server Configuration

FTP clients will then need to be configured to connect over "TLS/SSL".

Note: if this is not available based on your account permissions, then you'll have to upgrade to an account that does have this permission, a VPS, or a dedicated server.